# barman check - what do the Error Messages mean?

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman

Trying to get wal-streaming backups for PostgreSQL running with a barman backup server I face quite some errors on `barman check [postgres_server]`

here an example

```
:~> barman check pg
Server pg:
        WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)
        PostgreSQL: FAILED
        directories: OK
        retention policy settings: OK
        backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
        compression settings: OK
        failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
        minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 0 backups, expected at least 0)
        pg_basebackup: OK
        pg_basebackup compatible: FAILED (PostgreSQL version: None, pg_basebackup version: 12.6)
        systemid coherence: OK (no system Id available)
        pg_receivexlog: OK
        pg_receivexlog compatible: FAILED (PostgreSQL version: None, pg_receivexlog version: 12.6)
        receive-wal running: FAILED (See the Barman log file for more details)
        archiver errors: OK
```

as you see there is a lot of failed and it would be pretty helpful what the components here refer to actually. Is there any Glossary available anywhere explaining those values (`pg_basebackup compatible`, `receive-wal running:`, etc) ?

I haven't seen anything alike in the documentation thus far.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't seem to mention what the output means exactly, but there are comments (some good, some less so) in the [barman source code](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/barman).

WAL archive: Make sure that WAL archiving has been setup

PostgreSQL: Take the status of the remote server

superuser or standard user with backup privileges: Check for superuser privileges or privileges needed to perform backups

PostgreSQL streaming: If a streaming connection is available,  add its status to the output of the check

wal_level: Check wal_level parameter: must be different from 'minimal'

replication slot: Check the presence and the status of the configured replication slot. This check will be skipped if `slot_name` is undefined

directories: Checks backup directories and creates them if they do not exist

retention policy settings: Checks retention policy setting

backup maximum age: Check if backup validity requirements are satisfied

compression settings: Check compression_setting parameter

failed backups: Failed backups check

minimum redundancy requirements: Minimum redundancy checks

pg_basebackup: Check for the presence of pg_basebackup

pg_basebackup compatible: Perform additional checks for PostgresBackupExecutor

pg_basebackup supports tablespaces mapping: We can't backup a cluster with tablespaces if the tablespace mapping option is not available in the installed version of pg_basebackup.

systemid coherence: Check the systemid retrieved from the streaming connection is the same that is retrieved from the standard connection, and then verifies it matches the one stored on disk.

pg_receivexlog: Check the version of pg_receivexlog

pg_receivexlog compatible: Check the version of pg_receivexlog

receive-wal running: Check if pg_receivexlog is running, by retrieving a list of running 'receive-wal' processes from the process manager. If there's at least one 'receive-wal' process running for this server, the test is passed

archiver errors: Checks the presence of archiving errors

Comment: thx @hmallet. this is really great ... however would you mind to add the location of each action (i.e. _"pg_receivexlog compatible: Check the version of pg_receivexlog"_ ... on the barman backup server, or the PostgreSQL Server?)

Comment: I am a step further ... it seems the automatic connection to the PostgreSQL server does not qork despite the `.pgpass` file in my working directory. I'll try to solve that now, hoping some of the mentioned `FAILED` issues go away then.